# Login Only Works After Sending Curl Twice

Tags: php, forms, curl

I am trying to automate a task and I would like to grab some data from a website that requires login via a form.

Everything works, but the strange thing is that it only works the first time and then after that I can send any credentials and it says the login is successful because the cookie is storing my credentials. I tried to clear the cookie after each attempt to refresh the user session, but if I clear the cookie, I can never login because as it behaved before the first login attempt fails.

```
<?php

$cookie = "cookie.txt";

if (is_writable($cookie)) {
   // echo 'The cookie is writable';
} else {
   // echo 'The cookie is not writable';
   error_log("The cookie is not writable!", 3, "errors.log");
   ## start by making it writable :
   if (! chmod ( $cookie, 0777 ))
      die ( 'chmod() failed on file cookie.txt' );
}

function curl($url, $binary=false, $post=false, $cookie=false ){

$ch = curl_init();

$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);



    if($cookie){

        $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

    }


    if($binary)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

    if($post){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 return $result;
}

$getUser = $_GET["u"];
$getPass = $_GET["p"];

if (empty($getUser) || empty($getPass))
{
    $config = include 'config.php';
    $username = $config['username'];
    $password = $config['password'];
}

else 
{
    //echo "Using passed User & P/W!";
    $username = $getUser;
    $password = $getPass;
}

    $url=""; 

$postdata = "Account.UserName=".$username."&Account.PassWord=".$password."&action=/account/signin";

// function
$ch = curl($url, false, $postdata, $cookie);

// The below will request a URL inside your account to check for login success
$loginCheckURL = ""
$loginCheck = curl($loginCheckURL, false, false, $cookie);

preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i', substr($loginCheck, 300, 400), $titles);

if (strpos($titles[1],'Account Sign In') !== false) {
echo "Login Failed! <br><br>";
}
else echo "Login Successful! <br><br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing strange. It always works this way. First curl to get cookies, second curl to login. Server can't login you without cookies. People are doing the same. First you go to login form and you get cookies, next you send you login and password.

Comment: So can I just curl the login URL twice in my login function?

Comment: You can. But most scripts first curl (GET method) main page or page with login form and next curl to login (POST method). Some servers don't like bots or script so sometimes script have to behave like human. Server can check your cookies, UserAgent, referrer, time between opened pages (human can't open two pages in 35ms). Servers don't like bots because bots don't click in advertisements ;)

Comment: by the way: script to [login in ebay](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ebay_login.html) as example